# Change image source when image hits screen edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code for a dvd screensaver here.

I'd like to make it so every time the image hits the edge, it changes to a different image src. I can't seem to figure out how to change it.

I've tried using this technique:

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.src = 'img/new-image.jpg';
```

but I think i'm implementing it wrong because it doesnt seem to work. Any help is greatly apprecaited - snippet below.

```js
const section = document.querySelector("section");
const logo = document.querySelector(".logo");
const FPS = 60;
section.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
section.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";

// Logo moving velocity Variables
let xPosition = 10;
let yPosition = 10;
let xSpeed = 4;
let ySpeed = 4;
function update() {
  logo.style.left = xPosition + "px";
  logo.style.top = yPosition + "px";
}

setInterval(() => {
  if (xPosition + logo.clientWidth >= window.innerWidth || xPosition <= 0) {
    xSpeed = -xSpeed;
  }
  if (yPosition + logo.clientHeight >= window.innerHeight || yPosition <= 0) {
    ySpeed = -ySpeed;
  }

  xPosition += xSpeed;
  yPosition += ySpeed;
  update();
}, 1000 / FPS);

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  xPosition = 10;
  yPosition = 10;

  section.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
  section.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
section {
  position: relative;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  fill: rgb(0, 81, 255);
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  svg {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <svg class="logo"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <image id="imageID" href="https://i.imgur.com/gcrU9si.jpg" height="160" width="200"/>
  </svg>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this (https://jsfiddle.net/56emzjws/)

```js
function changeImage() {
   const img = document.getElementById("imageID");
   img.setAttribute("href",  (img.getAttribute("href") === "https://i.imgur.com/zmn2We7.jpeg") ? "https://i.imgur.com/gcrU9si.jpg" : "https://i.imgur.com/zmn2We7.jpeg");
}
```